# "in order not to" or "in order to not"?

Tags: grammar

Which one(s) is/are correct?
a. You need to practise speaking English in order not to be rusty.
b. You need to practise speaking English in order to not be rusty.
c. You need to practise speaking English in order to be not rusty.
d. all of them are correct.

Answer (score 5):

The most usual phrasing is probably one of these:

> You need to practise speaking English so you don't get rusty.
>
> You need to practise speaking English so you don't become rusty.

As for these:

> You need to practise speaking English in order **not to be** rusty.
>
> You need to practise speaking English in order **to not be** rusty.

Both are correct, but the so-called "split infinitive" ("to not be") is still occasionally frowned upon, so some writers prefer to avoid it in formal contexts.

> You need to practise speaking English in order **to be not** rusty.

This is an awkward phrasing and is only acceptable colloquially.  People would only be at all likely to say this if they had been discussing the idea of being "not rusty" immediately before, since here "not" is negating the following adjective rather than the verb.