# Not to speculate any more

Tags: difference

What is the difference between the following pair of sentences?

> He formed a resolution ***not to*** speculate any more.
>
> He formed a resolution ***to not*** speculate any more

Comment: Neither are particularly idiomatic compared to *He **resolved not to** speculate any more* (feasibly, *He **resolved to not** speculate any more*, but that's a rather stylised sequence).

Comment: Also [“to not do that” or “not to do that”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/99802/), [“in order not to” or “in order to not”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/150523/), [difference between not to verb , to not + verb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52958/), [verb+“to not”+infinitive OR verb+“not to”+infinitive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/194392/), and others.